# How to express the idea of "Ce n’est pas donné à tout le monde de ..."?

Tags: выражения, французский

> Tu as vraiment de la chance, XXX, **c’est pas donné à tout le monde d**’être amie avec un joueur de tennis mondialement connu.

We were having a conversation in French, and I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in Russian. This French expression literally means "***It's not given to everyone to*** (be friends with a world-renowned tennis player)", or more naturally, "***Not many people/folks get to*** (be friends with a world-renowned tennis player)".

The following sprang to mind as its Russian equivalent, but I wonder if using only "немногие" might not come across as a bit too plain, mundane?

> **Немногие** заводят друзей среди всемирно известных теннисистов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Немногие" is indeed the word to use here, other options are "не все" or "мало кто". There are lots of ways to make it less plain. For example

> Немногим доводится быть другом всемирно известному тенниситу
>
> Мало кому повезло подружиться со всемирно известным теннисистом
>
> Не всем случается завести дружбу со всемирно известным теннисистом

There is also addition that is closer to literal translation of the French phrase: "не всем дано", but it's mostly used for talents. E.g.

> Не всем дано красиво петь (not everyone has a talent for singing)

Comment: Ah, I see. Speaking of "**Не всем дано** (красиво петь)" to talk about one's talents, natures, it's kind of the opposite of "**Некоторым (просто) не дано** (красиво петь)", I take it?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens It is popular now to humorously use "не только лишь все" for this purpose. After the famous «А сегодня в завтрашний день не все могут смотреть. Вернее смотреть могут не только лишь все, мало кто может это делать» by [Klichko](http://klichko-citaty.ru/zavtrashnii-den-citata)  :)

Comment: @tum_ This "не только лишь все" is sort of an oxymoron, right?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens The whole quotation is an example of an extended "écart de langage" ;) It renders to nonsense and I couldn't stop laughing when I first heard this. Yeah, I think, "не только лишь все" qualifies as an oxymoron but it was not intenional, that's the fun of it.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens "не всем дано" is quite similar to "некоторым не дано" (literally "not everyone can" vs "some can not"), but the later is usually used when you actually mean a certain person (or persons).

Comment: @tum_ "не только лишь все" can be roughly translated as "not just only everyone". We can figure out what he meant, but the phrase itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does this one work just as well? "Мало кому **везёт** подружиться со всемирно известным теннисистом."

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens yes, it would.

Answer (score 1):

Мы говорим " **Не каждому выпадает** подружиться со всемирно известным теннисистом".

Tu as vraiment de la chance --подчеркивает эксклюзивность еще раз.

Comment: "Подружиться со всемирно известным теннисистом **— такое не каждому выпадает**". Hi. Does this sound natural enough?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens absolutely, or a bit more detailed **такая удача**

Comment: also **не каждому/не всем/не многим/мало кому случается + perf. infinitive**

Comment: Maybe it's better to write "не каждому выпадает **возможность**..."? // cc: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens

Comment: Чем короче,  тем лучше, тем выразительней, что выпадает — и так ясно, без классификации:такое, шанс, возможность, удача.

Comment: Тем более,  что "возможность" уже прозвучала в начале предложения.

Comment: Что-то никто не предложил "не каждому везёт", слишком просторечно?